# Atomic read-modify-write in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I've seen a couple of places quoting the following bit of the C# spec: "Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write." Can somebody point me to these library functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55dzx06b.aspx) class should provide you with what you are looking for; such as [Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) and [Decrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's referring to functions such as [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx).

This method can be used to, e.g., atomically update a `double`:

```
static void Add(ref double field, double amount)
{
    double before, after;
    do
    {
        before = field;
        after = before + amount;
    }
    while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, after, before) != before);
}
```